# ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm unable to find a module in python ,though easy_install says its already installed.
Any idea how to resolve this isseue?

```
$ python -c "from flaskext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy


$ python -V
Python 2.7


$ sudo easy_install sqlalchemy
Searching for sqlalchemy
Best match: SQLAlchemy 0.7.7
Adding SQLAlchemy 0.7.7 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for sqlalchemy
Finished processing dependencies for sqlalchemy
```

> $ sudo pip install SQLAlchemy --upgrade Requirement already
>   up-to-date: SQLAlchemy in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages Cleaning
>   up...

Though pip says it's installed.But I can't find them in sys.path output.

```
$ sudo python -c "import sys;print sys.path" ['',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask_SQLAlchemy-0.15-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.8-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.8.3-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask_WTF-0.5.2-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/WTForms-0.6.3-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask_Mail-0.6.1-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blinker-1.2-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lamson-1.1-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_daemon-1.6-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock-0.8.0-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/chardet-1.0.1-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lockfile-0.9.1-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask_FlatPages-0.2-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Markdown-2.1.1-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyYAML-3.10-py2.7-linux-i686.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/uWSGI-1.0.3-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg',
'/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
```

Comment: Started a bounty - As i found this issue again.After installing a package using pip "pip install python-bcrypt" today.

Comment: The ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy error occurs when Python is unable to find the SQLAlchemy module. to resolve this issue  try to install package through Pycharm IDE. for this go to PyCharm->Settings->Python Interpreter then click on + -> then search Flask-SQLAlchemy  select it and click on install package at bottom

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay,I have re-installed the package via pip even that didn't help. And then I rsync'ed the entire /usr/lib/python-2.7 directory from other working machine with similar configuration to
the current machine.It started working. I don't have any idea ,what was wrong with my setup. I see some difference "print sys.path" output earlier and now. but now my issue is resolved by this work around.

EDIT:Found the real solution for my setup. upgrading "sqlalchemy only doesn't solve the issue" I also need to upgrade `flask-sqlalchemy` that resolved the issue.

Comment: This workaround doesn't help now,since my other machine was down :(

Comment: why don't you just use virtualenv?

Comment: it's because your lib/site-packages of your python-env is polluted with a bad version of sqlchemy, and easy_install / pip first find there and check your "easy-install.pth" or "setuptools.pth" for installed packages, and stops if they find a broken version;

Answer (score 78):

Did you install [`flask-sqlalchemy`](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/)?  It looks like you have SQLAlchemy installed but not the Flask extension. Try `pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy` in your project's virtualenv to install it from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-SQLAlchemy/).

Comment: hmm..its also installed " easy_install Flask-SQLAlchemy
Searching for Flask-SQLAlchemy
Best match: Flask-SQLAlchemy 0.16
Adding Flask-SQLAlchemy 0.16 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for Flask-SQLAlchemy
Finished processing dependencies for Flask-SQLAlchemy
"

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04, pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy did the trick for me.

Comment: just adding an error I was having. I was using virtualenv and encountering this problem. Running `pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy` **without sudo** was what got it working for me.

Comment: Thanks on your answer D.S.

Answer (score 50):

I just experienced the same problem. Apparently, there is a new distribution method, the extension code is no longer stored under `flaskext`.

**Source:** Flask [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/commit/b2eac43ab2a13acdc037d16812c92649bcdf4680)
This worked for me:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Answer (score 27):

Install Flask-SQLAlchemy with pip in your virtualenv:

```
pip install flask_sqlalchemy
```

Then import `flask_sqlalchemy` in your code:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Comment: Yes, here's an example:
https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/examples/hello.py

Answer (score 5):

[try this](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html):

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Answer (score 5):

first install the library

```
pip install flask_sqlalchemy
```

after that

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

put this in app.py file to get the access of database through SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 4):

So here is an idea!

Since it seemed to work somewhere else.

install `python-virtualenv`
and optionally you can install virtualenv-wrapper (which is pretty cool to create projects and so on)

In each env, you might have different versions of eggs. In other word, you could have sqlalchemy 1 and sqlaclhemy 1.5 in two different envs and they won't conflict with each others. It seems that you have a problem with your currently installed eggs.

So here we go:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages foo
source foo/bin/activate
```

The parameter --no-site-packages will create a virtualenv and not use the packages already installed on your computer. It's pretty much like a bare python install.

`source foo/bin/activate` loads the virtualenv.

It's not that really userfriendly. And that's why http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/ exists.

That said, you should see somthing like thant in your terminal "(foo)user@domain$:" once your virtualenv is activated. It means that you can go on!

Then you have to do.

`python setup.py develop` of your project. It should download and install dependencies of your project in the virtualenv located in `foo`. If you need to install anything else, please use `pip` or `easy_install` without using `sudo`. When using virtualenv, you almost never need to use `sudo`. Sudo will install package in your global python install while it's not required and not really desirable.

If something happens in your virtualenv, you can always delete it and create a new one. This is no big deal. No need to mess with anything. Doesn't work? start over, do `pip install -U` if needed, define the versions if needed and so on.

Last but not least, in the other answers, it seems that the import changed. If the new versions for flask-sqlalchemy is located somewhere else, you should update your import or install the version you used to use.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new comer, use python 3.8 and met the same problem. I installed with `pip` instead of `pip3` because i thought the pip installer is the same for python2 and python3
so this is proper installation

`pip3 install flask_sqlalchemy`

Answer (score 2):

This code works perfectly:

```
import sqlalchemy
```

Maybe you installed the package in another version of the interpreter?

Also, like Shawley pointed out, you need to have the flask extension installed in order for it to be accessible.

Comment: no..even that didn't help "python -c "from flaskext.sqlalchemy import sqlalchemy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
"

Answer (score 1):

Probably a stupid mistake; but, I experienced this problem and the issue turned out to be that "pip3 install sqlalchemy" installs libraries in user specific directories.

On my Linux machine, I was logged in as user1 executing a python script in user2's directory. I installed sqlalchemy as user1 and it by default placed the files in user1's directory. After installing sqlalchemy in user2's directory the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was to use:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

instead of

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party but hopefully this will help someone, was in the same situation for about a hour without any of the solutions mentioned above working. (On a Windows 10 machine).

In the Settings/Preferences dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), from the side menu select Project:  | Project Interpreter.

Check which packages you currently have installed (You need SQLAlchemy and Flask-SQLAlchemy). Double click on any package name, an 'Available Packages' menu will open.

Search for the missing package(s) and click install.

Answer (score 0):

#### On Windows 10 @ 2019

I faced the same problem. Turns out I forgot to install the following package:

```
pip install flask_sqlalchemy
```

After installing the package, everything worked perfectly. Hope, it helped some other noob like me.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same problem using the virtual environment.
For me installing the package using python from the venv worked:

`.\venv\environment\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install flask-sqlalchemy`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is still relevant but try uninstalling sqlalchemy and then installing flask-sqlalchemy.

I guess if you have sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy wont work.

Tried in Python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem by a silly mistake. I have created a separate conda environment for flask from scratch. However, I tried to test the import of FlaskSQLAlchemy using IPython. Finally, I realized that it was the system-based python, not the one coming from conda env.
Always make sure that your `sys.path` contains the directory with flask_sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 0):

I was using virtualenv, even if the flask_sqlalchemy was installed, I was still getting it, what I did was to deactivate virtual environment, delete the flask from global packages, and delete virtual environment, create fresh one, install requirements again. And it worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the similar problem and the error message was:

```
Import "sqlalchemy" could not be resolved from source
```

and the solution was simply just choosing the right python interpreter which in this case was the python inside of my virtual environment.
and the credit of this solution is for "Borislav Hadzhiev" explained [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-import-could-not-be-resolved-from-source-pylance-reportmissingmodulesource)