# ImportError: No module named flask.ext.sqlalchemy in virtualenv

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Here is the main error I get when trying to run the following code in python3 from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jsnyder10/.local/bin/flask", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/jsnyder10/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 513, in main
cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 380, in main
return AppGroup.main(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/jsnyder10/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 423, in run_command
app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 152, in __init__
self._load_unlocked()
  File "/home/jsnyder10/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 176, in _load_unlocked
self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/home/jsnyder10/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 237, in load_app
rv = locate_app(self.app_import_path)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 90, in locate_app
__import__(module)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/CS50/pset7/pset7/finance/application.py", line 2, in <module>
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ImportError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

Not sure if it is related but when I update sqlaclhemy it gives the following pip heads up. I tried updating pip, but for some reason version 9.0.1 says it is upgraded but doesn't actually update.

```
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Here is what I get when I run pip list, as you can see both sqlalchemy and flask-sqlalchemy are installed.

```
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
appdirs (1.4.3)
click (6.7)
Flask (0.12.1)
Flask-SQLAlchemy (2.2)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.9.6)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
packaging (16.8)
pip (9.0.1)
pyparsing (2.2.0)
setuptools (35.0.2)
six (1.10.0)
SQLAlchemy (1.1.9)
Werkzeug (0.12.1)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

I'm guessing it was using the incorrect Python version. I never got to the bottom of this, but nuking my virtual machine and making a new one fixed it. Thanks for the help guys, wish I could have fixed it.

Comment: Do `pip list` and have a look if there is flask_sqlalchemy installed.

Comment: I posted the results of pip list in my main comment now. It says both sqlaclhemy and flask-sqlalchemy are installed.

Comment: I ran pip list and everything is installed properly. I am running this on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I even created a new virtual machine with a fresh Ubuntu and get the same error.

Comment: You probably have multiple python versions installed. Make sure pip has installed the package for the right one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572498/importerror-no-module-named-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 29):

The import statement:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

raises the exception `ImportError: No module named flask.ext.sqlalchemy in virtualenv` since the extension code is no longer stored under `flask.ext`, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10775143/1896134).

Therefore, the import statement should be changed to:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of:

```
  from flask.ext.mongoalchemy import MongoAlchemy
```

Use:

```
  from flask_mongoalchemy import MongoAlchemy
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, I'm using Flask-WhooshAlchemy (0.56) extension, but if you try to import it:
`import flask_whooshalchemy as whooshalchemy` that gives the reported error: `ImportError: No module named flask.ext.sqlalchemy`.

Then I have changed the import statement in Flask-WhooshAlchemy (line 18) from `import flask.ext.sqlalchemy as flask_sqlalchemy`
to `import flask_sqlalchemy as flask_sqlalchemy  # Modified`.

That solve the import error, but that means that you have a modified version of  Flask-WhooshAlchemy.

Answer (score 1):

try this
`pip install flask-sqlalchemy`

Comment: I did do that and it is installed according to pip list.

Comment: print `sys.path` in python prompt and see if the path is pointing to path where pip install packages