# Python ModuleNotFoundError package in azure app service

Tags: python, azure, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I using Python3.7 (Flask) webapp in Azure

also i was confirmed web app Stack runtime running Python3.7 too

The project working fine in 127.0.0.1:5000 (localhost)

When i try deployment script into azure webapp (App service)

i got this error :-

```
File "/home/site/wwwroot/init.py", line 2, in <module>
2019-12-16T15:50:45.275997228Z     from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
2019-12-16T15:50:45.276001128Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

i already install Flask-SQLAlchemy in venv (env)
runnning

```
$ pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

also i import Flask-SQLAlchemy into requirements.txt

```
flask_sqlalchemy==2.4.1
sqlalchemy==1.3.11
click==6.7
Flask==1.0.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
flask_admin==1.5.3
flask_login==0.4.1
pyodbc==4.0.27
```

i also run

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

my pip version is 19

```
$ pip -V 
pip 19.0.3 from /<project_path>/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

package install in venv

```
$ ls venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
Flask-1.0.2.dist-info           flask_sqlalchemy
Flask_Admin-1.5.3-py3.7.egg-info    itsdangerous-0.24-py3.7.egg-info
Flask_Login-0.4.1-py3.7.egg-info    itsdangerous.py
Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.4.1.dist-info    jinja2
Jinja2-2.10.dist-info           markupsafe
MarkupSafe-1.0-py3.7.egg-info       pip
SQLAlchemy-1.3.11.dist-info     pip-19.0.3.dist-info
WTForms-2.2.1.dist-info         pkg_resources
Werkzeug-0.14.1.dist-info       pyodbc-4.0.27.dist-info
__pycache__             pyodbc.cpython-37m-darwin.so
click                   setuptools
click-6.7.dist-info         setuptools-40.8.0.dist-info
easy-install.pth            sqlalchemy
easy_install.py             werkzeug
flask                   wheel
flask_admin             wheel-0.33.6.dist-info
flask_login             wtforms
```

.

Comment: maybe it doesn't use your venv to run it.

Comment: as default azure finding venv environment in project folder

Comment: I have the very same issue with the very same packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem because `venv` not export `antenv.tar.gz` file into webapp

Please don't use `az webapp up --sku F1 -n <app-name> -l <location-name>` to Redeploy updates

Use Local Git deployment to Azure App Service :-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git

Answer (score 0):

I would check my activated environment for this kind of situation as you have already checked that the package for SQLAlchemy is already available within the folder.

What might be happening is that you're using the system pip (pip3) to install flask-sqlalchemy to the system libs and then try to use it from within your venv. What also might be happening is that you successfully install flask-sqlalchemy to your venv and then use the system python (not venv) to try to import it.

Can you try installing the package from your venv:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59281844/6049604

Additional reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-dev-start-howto-vm-python?view=azs-1910

https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/9r0kmz/python_37_error_with_flasksqlalchemy/

Hope it helps.

Comment: the problem not from just flask-sqlalchemy package
any new package in requirements.txt not installing
also i have another app working fine Maybe because is antenv.tar.gz file in wwwroot
my app had problem not have antenv.tar.gz
so venv not working because venv import in webapp