# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' in application service azure with flask

Tags: python, pandas, azure

Help,
my application works normally on my device, but on azure the error occurs:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

The source:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, redirect

import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def inicio():

    return render_template('index.html')

    
@app.route('/lista', methods=("POST", "GET"))

def html_table():

    return render_template('lista.html')

    
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run()
```

In browser returns:
:( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

If I remove the panda it works normally. I'm still getting to know azure.

Comment: You need to install `pandas` in your remote device.  You already installed `flask`, right?  Because neither one is built-in.

Comment: Hello, error in azure:

Comment: Do you have requirements.txt file in your project code?

Comment: I have requirements.txt file in my project code, for deployment in Azure for configuration app service add setting SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT value 1 then success

Comment: Is the issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

If you see an error like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example'`, this means that Python could not find one or more of your modules when the application started. This most often occurs if you deploy your virtual environment with your code. Virtual environments are not portable, so a virtual environment should not be deployed with your application code.

Instead, let Oryx create a virtual environment and install your packages on the web app by creating an app setting, `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT`, and setting it to `1`. This will force Oryx to install your packages whenever you deploy to App Service.

> This you have done this setting and got it

If you need more information, please refer please see [this article on virtual environment portability](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/12/11/cicd-for-python-apps.html), the [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59360451/python-modulenotfounderror-package-in-azure-app-service) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/122340/azure-webapp-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-p.html).