# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, cs50

I use `Anaconda` and `Flask` to create a simple webapp but I cannot manage to import `SQLAlchemy` in my `Python` code.

Here is my code to import `SQLAlchemy`: `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`

Here is the terminal message.

[Although I tried to use pip to install it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diTm0.png)

But I still get

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10572551/6505847)

Comment: Hard to say what exactly went wrong without having a code to run. That's being said, my bet is that you did not install the library properly. Make sure you use a correct version of Pip for your Python version (i.e. on some Linux distributions you may have `pip3` for Python 3.* and `pip` for Python 2.*). Also check this: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: conda use python=3.8 and I already install "pip install flask-sqlalchemy"